# What is the Best way to Append Values to a Column From other Columns Within Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The source system from which I receive data has an odd structure. I want to know is there a better way to process it than the one I have found. First, here is how the data looks:

```
ID    med_A    med_B    med_C    med_D
AA    cold     flu      nasal    Nan
AA    pain     cold     Nan      Nan
BB    bleed    heart    Nan      Nan
CC    cold     bleed    Nan      Nan
```

To explain, each ID is a unique patient, and each patient may have many rows. A single row represents a single visit to the doctor. The columns med_A, ..., med_D are different medical diagnoses the patient receives. The oddity about the source system is that the latter columns are filled after the earlier ones. So on a single visit, the patient's first diagnosis goes into med_A, their second into med_B, and so on.

I want to collapse the columns down so that I instead have:

```
ID    MED
AA    cold
AA    flu
AA    nasal
AA    pain
AA    cold
BB    bleed
BB    heart
CC    cold
CC    bleed
```

Also please note the additional complexity: in reality the columns aren't nicely named and ordered. I have over twenty such columns, dispersed unevenly across hundreds of columns that serve other purposes, and also they have no naming convention.

CURRENT SOLUTION:

Currently I manually pull out all the relevant column names and store them in a list called *columns*. Also, the main dataframe that stores everything is called *df*.

Then my code looks like this:

```
for column in columns:
    df_temp = df[['ID', '{}'.format(column)]]  # build temporary df to store first column
    df_temp.columns = ['ID', 'MED'] # Set a column naming convention
    df = df.append(df_temp)
df.drop(columns=columns)  # Get rid of excess columns, only want MED
```

The problems with this method are:
 - Hard to scale up
 - For loops in pandas are slow

I want to know: is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and double [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) - first for remove second level and second for convert index to column:

```
df = df.set_index('ID').stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index(name='MED')
print (df)
   ID    MED
0  AA   cold
1  AA    flu
2  AA  nasal
3  AA   pain
4  AA   cold
5  BB  bleed
6  BB  heart
7  CC   cold
8  CC  bleed
```